# Reading the filesystem of localhost using native JavaScript

Tags: javascript, url, filesystems, localhost

I am currently trying to create the possibility in a script to find all the items below root in a localhost copy of a filesystem directory

I have searched around but I can't find anyone trying to make requests for information from localhost.

Say my localhost directory root looked like:

`a_file.txt
another_file.json
svg.js
a_dir`

Ideally I'd like to be able to test the url: `http://localhost:8080/` and be able to detect immediate children of this url, i.e: return: `['a_file.txt', 'another_file.json', 'svg.js', 'a_dir']`, then I can request (for example) `http://localhost:8080/svg.js.

Specifically I want this functionality because I am using [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) on npm to host, meaning in theory I could host any directory in my filesystem

Comment: Well you would need code on the server.... You can not do it from the browser.

Comment: Basically you need an (s)ftp server listening to localhost:8080. It's possible to implement using http, but it may require building some extra plumbing

Comment: Sound like it might be more effort than it's worth then, it's only for personal use so changing a hard-coded path sounds much less painful